# Simple SPI Master

Tags: hdl, vhdl

I wrote a simple SPI Master implementation to send characters to a LCD screen. Only the output is actually implemented in this so there is no rx register. This only sends a character out when write is asserted. I would appreciate any feedback and wanted to test out stackexchange for HDL.

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;
use IEEE.numeric_std.all;
-- Entity and Architecture Definitions
entity spi_master is
generic (
REG_SIZE : integer := 8;
CLK_DIV : integer := 25); -- This runs 2x slower then sys clock
-- so to divide 50 Mhz to 1Mhz div by 25 not 50
port (
    clk: in std_logic; -- 1 Mhz provided by system
    data: in std_logic_vector(REG_SIZE-1 downto 0);
    write: in std_logic; -- begin sending out register contents
    cpol: in std_logic;
    cpha: in std_logic;
    rst: in std_logic;
    spi_clock: out std_logic;
    mosi: out std_logic;
    ss: out std_logic);
end entity spi_master;
architecture spi_master of spi_master is
signal spi_clk : std_logic; -- temp spi clock (twice as slow as clk)
signal tx_reg : std_logic_vector(REG_SIZE-1 downto 0); -- temp transmit
register
signal count : integer; -- count
signal toggle_count : integer;
type machine is (ready, low_cpha, high_cpha);
signal state : machine;
signal spi_en : std_logic;
signal write_strobe : std_logic;
signal write_strobe_sync0 : std_logic;
signal write_strobe_sync1 : std_logic;
begin

spi_clock <= spi_clk;

process(clk,write_strobe_sync1, rst)
begin

    if(rst = '0') then
        mosi <= 'Z';
        state <= ready;
        count <= REG_SIZE;
        ss <= '1';
    elsif rising_edge(clk) then

    case state is
        when ready =>
        tx_reg <= data; -- load temp register with data
        mosi <= 'Z';
        count <= (REG_SIZE*2); -- running 2x slower then clock
        toggle_count <= CLK_DIV;
        spi_clk <= cpol;
        ss <= '1';
        if (write_strobe_sync1 = '1' and cpha = '0') then
            spi_en <= '0'; -- delay the enable half an spi_clk period
            ss <= '0';
            state <= low_cpha;
        elsif(write_strobe_sync1 = '1' and cpha = '1') then
            spi_en <= '1';
            ss <= '0';
            state <= high_cpha;
        else
            state <= ready;
        end if;

    when low_cpha =>
    if(toggle_count = 0) then -- toggle spi_clk CLK_DIV
        toggle_count <= CLK_DIV; -- count for 1Mhz
        if(spi_en = '1') then
            count <= count - 1;
            if(count /= 16) then
                spi_clk <= not spi_clk; -- makes this 2x slower then clk
            end if;
        else -- send out mosi even if spi_clk isnt enabled for low cpha
            mosi <= tx_reg(REG_SIZE-1); -- shift out mosi
            tx_reg <= tx_reg(REG_SIZE-2 downto 0) & '0';
            spi_en <= '1';
        end if;
        if(cpol /= spi_clk ) then
            mosi <= tx_reg(REG_SIZE-1);
            tx_reg <= tx_reg(REG_SIZE-2 downto 0) & '0';
        end if;
        if(count = 0) then
            state <= ready;
        else

        state <= low_cpha;
    end if;
else
    toggle_count <= toggle_count - 1;
end if;

when high_cpha =>
if(spi_en = '1') then
   -- run spi at CLK_DIV
   if(toggle_count = 0) then
       count <= count - 1;
       toggle_count <= CLK_DIV;
       if(count /= 0) then
           spi_clk <= not spi_clk; -- makes this 2x slower then clk
           -- shift out data to mosi
           if(cpol = spi_clk ) then
               mosi <= tx_reg(REG_SIZE-1);
               tx_reg <= tx_reg(REG_SIZE-2 downto 0) & '0';
           end if;
       end if;
       -- Change to the next state
       if(count = 0) then
           state <= ready;
       else
           state <= high_cpha;
       end if;
   else
       toggle_count <= toggle_count - 1;
   end if;
   else   
      spi_en <= '1';
   end if;
   end case;
end if;
end process;

-- Syncronize asyncrounous input
latch_write: process(write, write_strobe_sync1, rst)
begin
    if(write_strobe_sync1 = '1' or rst = '0') then
        write_strobe <= '0';
    elsif rising_edge(write) then
        write_strobe <= '1';
    end if;
end process;

sync_write: process(clk, rst, write_strobe)
begin
    if(rst = '0') then
        write_strobe_sync0 <= '0';
        write_strobe_sync1 <= '0';
    elsif rising_edge(clk) then
        write_strobe_sync0 <= write_strobe;
        write_strobe_sync1 <= write_strobe_sync0;
    end if;
end process;

end architecture spi_master;
```

Comment: Please at least indent your code consistently!

Answer (score 1):

Never saw HDL before, but the following came to mind

1. Indentation seems wrong, I would have expected `case state` to be indented

   ```
   elsif rising_edge(clk) then

   case state is
   ```
2. `mosi <= 'Z';` <- Why 'Z', that could use a comment
3. `if(rst = '0') then` it seems from your code that the brackets are unnecessary, you should either put them everywhere or nowhere for style consistency
4. Obvious newbie remark: `tx_reg <= tx_reg(REG_SIZE-2 downto 0) & '0';` How is this different from `tx_reg <= '0'` ?

Comment: 2) 'Z' is a specific HDL value that means a lot to us hardware types without a comment. 4) `&` is a concatenation operator in VHDL (not bitwise and)

Answer (score 1):

First thing you need to do is get your sensitivity lists correct.

```
process (clk)
```

is all that is required for a synchronous process and

```
process (clk, rst)
```

if you have an asynchronous reset signal.

You don't need all the other signals unless it is a combinational process (like latch_write is) but it's error-prone, so I find it much safer to make everything a clocked process.